# animating images which are stored in sqlite table

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xcode4.3

I have this snippet in my ViewDidAppear()

```
photosImgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"], 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-small-50.png"], nil];
```

Here the images which are listed should be there in the bundle,its working correct but what i want is instead of taking the images from bundle to photosImgView .
I want to take the images which are there in sqlite table with column name PPhotos to photosImgView to animate.

How can i do this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you storing image in database or image name in database ?

Comment: SqliteTableObj.photo=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImg, 1.0);

Comment: storing the image as BLOB using the above statement..

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestions:**

- Never save image in database, because it'll make your database heavy
- You can save image in document directory and add the path to database
- If you are using photolibrary image save the asset-url in database

**Solution:**

You can read the data from database using the select query

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getImage
{
  NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSmutableArray alloc] init];
  if (sqlite3_open([yourDatabasePath UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *select_sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select PPhotos from imageTable];
    const char *sql = [select_sql UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selectstmt, 0) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(selectstmt, 0)];           
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageArray]];
        }
    }

  return [imageArray autorelease];
}
```

Here the `getImage` will return all the images stored in the database.